# css flipping cards in different browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi i need to make flipping cards effect in different browsers but it correctly works only in chrome and opera...in different browsers it doesn't change image or change image but doesn't flipp... can you help me?? this is my CSS code:

```
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

and this is my Html code:

```
<div id="sekcia">
                <a href="http://<?echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/sk/hudba">             <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front">
                            <img src="http://<?echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/titulna/hudba.png"><!-- front content -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <img src="http://<?echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/titulna/hudba1.png"><!-- back content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I have different than your code is:

```
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: it worked for firefox thx :) but I need that also for safari and explorer :D

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer right now, but could you do the same thing with the -moz-transform and -webkit-transform?

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: I seem to have the same code as you and mine works. Are you using updated versions of Safari and IE?

Comment: Your site works fine in my Safari. (8.0.3) and IE (11.0.9600.17501)

Comment: i have the same versions and in explorer it doesnt change image only rotate it and in safari it only change image and doesnt rotate it

Comment: The only differences between mine and yours are that you have a div enclosing it all with an ID of "sekcia", where as I don't, and in my CSS I put  backface-visibility: hidden before the -moz and -webkit lines. (the same for transform, etc.) I don't know if that would matter though.